# Multiple tabs in one HTML page without unique reference (no ID or class)

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

Is it possible to have multiple tabs in one HTML page without unique reference, i.e. no IDs or classes as reference for the content to be displayed when clicking the tab. The code below is just to visualize it how it could look like. It is pure CSS and uses IDs. Multiple of such sections with the tabs should appear in one HTML page. The code should work without any manually predefined stuff since this code pattern with tabs should be reused multiple times on multiple HTML pages, hence, it should be generic. I was thinking of a potential solution with JS and nextElementSibling or suchlike. Can anyone support and post a solution (not necessarily in the example; ideally with pure JS, no library)?

```css
    body {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

* {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion {
  margin: 94px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.accordion input.tab-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.accordion input.tab-toggle:checked + label {
  background: white;
}
.accordion input.tab-toggle:checked + label .tab-title:hover {
  background: transparent;
}
.accordion input.tab-toggle:checked + label .tab {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.accordion label {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.accordion label:first-of-type .tab {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}
.accordion label .tab-title {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.accordion label .tab-title:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.accordion .tab {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 56px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 244px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque felis mi, vulputate et lorem quis, blandit pharetra metus. Donec viverra accumsan velit at ullamcorper.
</p>
<div class="accordion">
  <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" id="tab_one" checked/>
  <label for="tab_one">
    <span class="tab-title">Tab One</span>
    <div class="tab" id="tab_one_wrapper">
      <p>Hi. I'm tab one's content. Nice to meet you.</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" id="tab_two" />
  <label for="tab_two">
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Two</span>
    <div class="tab" id="tab_two_wrapper">
      <p>Hi. I'm tab two's content. Nice to meet you.</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" id="tab_three" />
  <label for="tab_three">
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Three</span>
    <div class="tab" id="tab_three_wrapper">
      <p>Hi. I'm tab three's content. Nice to meet you.</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" id="tab_four" />
  <label for="tab_four">
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Four</span>
    <div class="tab" id="tab_four_wrapper">
      <p>Hi. I'm tab four's content. Nice to meet you.</p>
    </div>
  </label>


</div>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque felis mi, vulputate et lorem quis, blandit pharetra metus. Donec viverra accumsan velit at ullamcorper.
</p>

<div class="accordion">

  <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" id="tab_five" />
  <label for="tab_five">
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Five</span>
    <div class="tab" id="tab_five_wrapper">
      <p>Tab Five</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" id="tab_six"/>
  <label for="tab_six">
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Six</span>
    <div class="tab" id="tab_six_wrapper">
      <p>Six</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" id="tab_seven" />
  <label for="tab_seven">
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Seven</span>
    <div class="tab" id="tab_seven_wrapper">
      <p>Seven</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" id="tab_eight" />
  <label for="tab_eight">
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Eight</span>
    <div class="tab" id="tab_eight_wrapper">
      <p>Eight</p>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: The given CSS doesn't rely on `id` at all. It's already re-usable

Comment: @TJ CSS doesn't, but the labels are assigned to radio buttons by IDs.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert your radio buttons inside `<label>` you don't have to use ids:

```css
body {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

* {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion {
  margin: 94px auto 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.accordion input.tab-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.accordion label input.tab-toggle:checked + .tab-title {
  background: white;
}
.accordion label input.tab-toggle:checked ~ .tab {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.accordion label {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.accordion label:first-of-type .tab {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 3px;
}
.accordion label .tab-title {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.accordion label .tab-title:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.accordion .tab {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 56px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 244px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque felis mi, vulputate et lorem quis, blandit pharetra metus. Donec viverra accumsan velit at ullamcorper.
</p>
<div class="accordion">
  <label>
    <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" checked/>
    <span class="tab-title">Tab One</span>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Hi. I'm tab one's content. Nice to meet you.</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" />
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Two</span>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Hi. I'm tab two's content. Nice to meet you.</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" />
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Three</span>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Hi. I'm tab three's content. Nice to meet you.</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" />
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Four</span>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Hi. I'm tab four's content. Nice to meet you.</p>
    </div>
  </label>


</div>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque felis mi, vulputate et lorem quis, blandit pharetra metus. Donec viverra accumsan velit at ullamcorper.
</p>

<div class="accordion">

  <label>
    <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" />
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Five</span>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Tab Five</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group"/>
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Six</span>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Six</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" />
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Seven</span>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Seven</p>
    </div>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input class="tab-toggle" type="radio" name="my_radio_group" />
    <span class="tab-title">Tab Eight</span>
    <div class="tab">
      <p>Eight</p>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thx! very promising. One remark: It is however not really usable for me this way. The first of each tab section that will potentially be there should be visible/checked. That's not possible in this example, right, since the tab clicking in one section affects the other sections? This should not be. Each section should be independent of each other (that's why I think the base example is somewhat suboptimal). Any ideas?